# Zend Framework 2 page reloads two times

Tags: zend-framework2

Every time I open a view page. I notice that ZF2 web page reloads two times. I can see it when I use javascript alert() function and it alerts two times, each time I refresh the web page. My problem is when I append option to form select element, one option is added twice because the web page is reloaded twice. How can I prevent the web page from reloading two times? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Can you please provide some more information or/and the code -- the view script and how you include it into the layout.

Comment: Dear Automatix, I just found the cause of the problem. In my index.phtml I added this line of code: echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/custom-nkhmer-jquery.js'); Actually I should not echo it, so after removing the word 'echo' my application reloads the index page only one time now. If echo this line of code, the application will refresh the page two times. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you found an answer to your own question you should post it as an answer. You can accept if after a day or so an even get a badge for it.

Comment: I don't know why I should post it as an answer, but I did post it as an answer as you said.

Answer (score 2):

I just found the cause of the problem. In my index.phtml I added this line of code: echo $this->headScript()->prependFile($this->basePath() . '/js/custom-nkhmer-jquery.js'); Actually I should not echo it, so after removing the word 'echo' my application reloads the index page only one time now. If echo this line of code, the application will refresh the page two times. Thank you anyway!

Comment: It seems you loaded your javascript twice. The page did not reload twice, your application executed twice. It is a crucial difference to understand.

Comment: Yeah, Marr75 you are right. In fact I didn't even know that I loaded the javascript twice when I put echo before headScript().